# How to update single package in pubspec.yaml file in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Let's say I'm having two packages in my `pubspec.yaml` file.

```
abc: any
xyz: any
```

Now, I only want to update `abc` package, how do I do that, is there any command like

```
flutter update abc
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To upgrade `abc` package and leaving others as it is, run:

```
dart pub upgrade abc
```

To upgrade all the packages, run:

```
dart pub upgrade
```

Answer (score 4):

First, comment that the packaging line in the `pubspec.yaml` file and run `flutter pub get` after successfully get packages to uncomment that line (if you want to upgrade/downgrade to a specific version that mentioned version too) it will upgrade to the latest version.

In your case:

step 1:

```
// abc: any
   xyz: any
```

- run `flutter pub get`

step 2:

```
  abd: any
  xyz: any
```

So now `abc` will upgrade to the latest version

Comment: @iKeepChangingName Agreed but Currently, I am using these steps in my flutter project.

Comment: @iKeepChangingName try [Upgrading specific dependencies](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-upgrade#upgrading-specific-dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio for Flutter you can install this plugin.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12693-flutter-enhancement-suite/

I'm not using Visual Studio, so I don't know if these plugins are what you need but you can check

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jeroen-meijer.pubspec-assist

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=everettjf.pubspec-dependency-search

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GulajavaMinistudio.complete-flutter-extension-pack

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in the terminal

```
pub upgrade abc args
```

where `abc` is the package name you want to upgrade. Be sure you are in the project root directory.

Comment: Because `my_package` depends on flutter_test any from sdk which doesn't exist (the Flutter SDK is not available), version solving failed.